# Kentico 10 UnitTests don`t work OneTimeSetUp NullReferenceException

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, kentico

I have a problem running the Kentico UnitTests. I get the following error:

> *NUnit Adapter 3.6.1.0: Test execution started Running selected tests in xxxxxx.dll NUnit3TestExecutor converted 1 of 1 NUnit test cases
>   SetUp failed for test fixture xxxxxx_tests.ContentCreator_test
>   System.NullReferenceException : Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine
>   Objektinstanz festgelegt.    bei
>   CMS.Tests.TestsCategoryCheck.GetCategoriesFromConfig(String keyName)
>
>   bei CMS.Tests.TestsCategoryCheck.<.cctor>b__8()    bei
>   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()    bei System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
>
>   bei System.Lazy`1.get_Value()    bei
>   CMS.Tests.TestsCategoryCheck.CheckAllTestsCategories(Type type)    bei
>   CMS.Tests.AutomatedTests.InitFixtureBase()*

**How can I fix it ?**

I installed the `Kentico.Library.Tests` and wrote this test:

```
using CMS.Membership;
using CMS.Tests;
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public class MyUnitTests : UnitTests
{
[SetUp]
public void MyUnitTestSetUp()
{
    // Prepares faked data for the UserInfoProvider
    Fake<UserInfo, UserInfoProvider>().WithData(
        new UserInfo
        {
            UserID = 123,
            UserName = "FakeUser",
            UserNickName = "FakeUser"
        });
}

[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    // Calls a UserInfoProvider method to get user data
    var users = UserInfoProvider.GetUsers();
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please let me know some scenarios that i need write unit test case for a site,which just having no interactions Just a customer facing website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a bug but my fault.
DLL mixed :/